# How to solve two-level Schrödinger equation using Floquet theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a sinusoidal driving two-level system:

$$
i \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \dot C_1(t) \\
 \dot C_2(t) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{\omega _0}{2} & \Omega(t)\cos(\omega t)\\
 \Omega(t)\cos(\omega t) & \frac{\omega _0}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 C_1(t) \\
 C_2(t) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $C_1(t)$ and $C_2(t)$ are the state amplitude for the two states.

If $\Omega(t)$ is a constant, then the hamiltonian is periodic in time and thus the above equation can be solved using the standard [Floquet theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory).

I'm intreated in the case of $\Omega(t)$ has a pulse shape 
$$
\Omega(t)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
             \Omega_0\sin^2(\pi t/\tau) & 0\leq t<\tau\\[1em]
             0 & \tau \leq t
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
where $\tau\gg\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$.

How to solve the above equation using the Floquet formalism? I'm not seeking the complete analytical solution, what I want is just the procedure to carried out the perturbation or numerical solution.